# Assign value to a column if column name contains matches value from another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below and I want to assign value=1 to columns (batch_typea_2021,    batch_typea_2022, batch_typea_2023...., batch_typeb_2021, batch_typeb_2022, batch_typeb_2023...) based on year in columns typea_date, typeb_date. I do not want to hard code the year.

```
df
record_id   typea_date  typeb_date  batch_typea_2021    batch_typea_2022    batch_typea_2023    batch_typea_2024    batch_typeb_2021    batch_typeb_2022    batch_typeb_2023    batch_typeb_2024
Emp-1   12/10/21 11:08                                  
Emp-2   12/4/21 11:06                                   
Emp-3   12/6/22 4:20                                    
Emp-4   12/7/21 11:21                                   
Emp-5   2/11/22 18:59   12/4/21 11:06                               
Emp-6   12/6/21 4:20                                    
Emp-7   12/4/23 11:07   12/7/21 11:21                               
Emp-8       12/5/24 11:07
```

Desired Output:

```
record_id   typea_date  typeb_date  batch_typea_2021    batch_typea_2022    batch_typea_2023    batch_typea_2024    batch_typeb_2021    batch_typeb_2022    batch_typeb_2023    batch_typeb_2024
    Emp-1   12/10/21 11:08      1                           
    Emp-2   12/4/21 11:06       1                           
    Emp-3   12/6/22 4:20            1                       
    Emp-4   12/7/21 11:21       1                           
    Emp-5   2/11/22 18:59   12/4/21 11:06       1           1           
    Emp-6   12/6/21 4:20        1                           
    Emp-7   12/4/23 11:07   12/7/21 11:21           1       1           
    Emp-8       12/5/24 11:07                               1
```

Comment: please share the actual data for `df` instead of a formatted table. you can use `dput(df)` and `dput(desired_output)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
 left_join(pivot_longer(.,-record_id, names_to = c('type', '.value'),
                names_sep = '_', 
                values_transform = ~year(mdy_hm(.x)),
                values_drop_na = TRUE)%>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = record_id, 
               names_from = c(type,date), 
               names_prefix = 'batch_',
               values_from = date,values_fn = length))


  record_id     typea_date    typeb_date batch_typea_2021 batch_typea_2022 batch_typeb_2021
1     Emp-1 12/10/21 11:08                              1               NA               NA
2     Emp-2  12/4/21 11:06                              1               NA               NA
3     Emp-3   12/6/21 4:20                              1               NA               NA
4     Emp-4  12/7/21 11:21                              1               NA               NA
5     Emp-5  2/11/22 18:59 12/4/21 11:06               NA                1                1
6     Emp-6   12/6/21 4:20                              1               NA               NA
7     Emp-7  12/4/21 11:07 12/7/21 11:21                1               NA                1
```

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in "Joining with"

Comment: @akang the line `Joining with` is an output. The same way the table is an output. do not copy paste it to your console